# Store and invalidate Java HttpSession from different user

Tags: java, session, jetty, invalidation, httpsession

Okay. What I want to do is be able to, when I update a user, invalidate any session that they currently have in order to force a refresh of credentials. I don't care about being able to directly access the session-specific user data. Ideally, I would also be able to restrict users to one session by a similar manner.

What I tried doing is creating a HashMap using the username as key and HttpSession as the value (my actual setup is a little more involved, but after repeated seemingly inexplicable failures, I boiled it down to this simple test). However, whenever I attempt to tell the retrieved HttpSession to invalidate, it seems to be invalidating the current [admin] session. Is HttpSession inextricably bound to the current request?

Or is there an entirely different way to deal with this?

If it happens to matter, I'm using Jetty 6.1.26.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no straight forward way. The easiest way I can think of is to keep a flag on the database (or a cahche) and check it's validity on each request.

Or you can implement a HTTP Session listener and keep a HashMap of user sessions that can be accessed and invalidated.

I haven't tried any of these out so I don't know of any performance issues. But it should be acceptable for most applications.

Comment: That's almost exactly the setup I had (the session listener). The issue was when calling session.invalidate(), it invalidated the session I was invalidating from, rather than the target session. My thoughts are to set up an invalid flag in a session-scoped bean and just use an aspect to verify and invalidate from there. Or I guess I could do the verification from a request-scoped bean. Either way, it gets me to the same place (depending on whether the aspect or instantiation occurs first).

Comment: When you called invalidate on the sessions of other users from that map you were the only one invalidated? Maybe your session was in the Map and it was invalidated as well....

Comment: Yes. The target session remained unaffected.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as far as I can tell, there's no way around it. Using a request-scoped bean didn't work as I expected (although it did give me good insights into how Spring operates, intercepting field accesses). I ended up using a dirty flag on my SessionHandler (a session-scoped bean) with a very high-priority aspect checking and, if necessary, calling invalidate() on the session in the user's next request. I still ended up having all my SessionHandlers register with a SessionManager, and a @PreDestroy method to unregister them in order to avoid a bunch of null entries in the map.